# Update rows in one table, with data from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `CountLogs` and `RegisterCountLogs`.  They both have the same FK constraints, so I'd like to transfer the Timestamp from one to the other.  How can I achieve this in one SQL statement?

E.g.

```
SELECT [DeviceSerial]
      ,[LogEntryID]
      ,[Timestamp]
  FROM [dbo].[CountLogs]

UPDATE RegisterCountLogs 
    SET Timestamp = [OTHERQUERY?].Timestamp 
    WHERE [DeviceSerial] = [OTHERQUERY?].[DeviceSerial] 
        AND [OTHERQUERY?][LogEntryID] = [OTHERQUERY?].[LogEntryID]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
UPDATE RegisterCountLogs 
    SET Timestamp = [OTHERQUERY?].Timestamp 
    FROM       RegisterCountLogs
    INNER JOIN [OTHERQUERY?]     ON RegisterCountLogs.DeviceSerial = [OTHERQUERY?].[DeviceSerial] 
                                AND RegisterCountLogs.[LogEntryID] = [OTHERQUERY?].[LogEntryID]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
UPDATE R 
SET R.Timestamp = C.Timestamp 
FROM RegisterCountLogs R
INNER JOIN [dbo].[CountLogs] C ON 
(R.[DeviceSerial] = C.[DeviceSerial] 
 AND R.[LogEntryID] = C.[LogEntryID])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;With Cte_countlogs as 
 (
  SELECT [DeviceSerial]
  ,[LogEntryID]
  ,[Timestamp]
  FROM [dbo].[CountLogs]
 )

 UPDATE RegisterCountLogs 
 SET Timestamp = Cte_countlogs .Timestamp
 from  
 RegisterCountLogs
 JOIN  Cte_countlogs ON RegisterCountLogs.DeviceSerial = Cte_countlogs .[DeviceSerial] 
 AND RegisterCountLogs.[LogEntryID] = Cte_countlogs.[LogEntryID]
```